# why my array doen't works when is in my loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have the next code...

```js
function feed() {
  var userId = "a";
  var keys = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).child("following").once('value').then(function(datakey) {
    let usersPost = {};
    let contador = 0;
    let rangeNumbers = [20, 15, 5];
    datakey.forEach(function(data) {
      let userDB = data.val();
      let userIdFollowing = userDB.id;
      firebase.database().ref('posts/').orderByChild("id").equalTo(userIdFollowing).once('value').then(function(postdatakey) {
        postdatakey.forEach(function(postdata) {
          //Detecta todos los datos de la publicacion
          let postDB = postdata.val();
          let postId = postDB.id;
          usersPost[contador] = postDB;
          rangeNumbers.push(contador);
          contador++;
        });
      });
    });

    //console.log(usersPost);
    //Randomize here

    var randomi = rangeNumbers;
    randomi = shuffle(randomi);
    console.log(randomi);
  });
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return array;
}
```

This code add 1,2,3 to my array.
My new array is  rangeNumbers=[20,15,5,1,2,3];
But when I want to randomize it my output is:

15, 20, 5, 1, 2, 3.
I was thinking that it was a problem in the shuffle function but it is not the problem.

In the console I see:
Array(3) [ 5, 20, 15 ]

but when I open I can see my output 15, 20, 5, 1, 2, 3.
The function only works for the original array created.

Please help me I want to randomize all my array and my code only randomize the first three numbers (original array).

Comment: The question is quite confusing. What works and what not? You mean the elements are not getting pushed in array?

Comment: @randomSoul My code only randomize the first three numbers (my original array) and dont randomize the numbers added through the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase code is running asynchronously, and you're shuffling the array before the callback function runs. You need to move that code into the callback function.

```js
function feed() {
  var userId = "a";
  var keys = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).child("following").once('value').then(function(datakey) {
    let usersPost = {};
    let contador = 0;
    let rangeNumbers = [20, 15, 5];
    datakey.forEach(function(data) {
      let userDB = data.val();
      let userIdFollowing = userDB.id;
      firebase.database().ref('posts/').orderByChild("id").equalTo(userIdFollowing).once('value').then(function(postdatakey) {
        postdatakey.forEach(function(postdata) {
          //Detecta todos los datos de la publicacion
          let postDB = postdata.val();
          let postId = postDB.id;
          usersPost[contador] = postDB;
          rangeNumbers.push(contador);
          contador++;
        });
        //Randomize here
        var randomi = rangeNumbers;
        randomi = shuffle(randomi);
        console.log(randomi);
      });
    });
  });
}
```